# Trigonometric computations for thin film interference

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I don't know how to properly entitle my post. I'd like to know how you get from the 5th to the 6th step, indicated with a very discrete red arrow and question mark.

[image]

Comment: What are $t, g, \lambda_0,\lambda_1$?

Comment: Hmm. This looks like thin film interference; if so, the Wikipedia article on [thin-film interference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin-film_interference) is pretty clear step-wise. It matches if $\operatorname{tg}\theta_2 = \tan\theta_2$ and $\lambda_n = \lambda_0$. On the other hand, that $\lambda_n$ throws me off. Do you trust the source? If I were you, I'd expect it is a typo; maybe the writer confused refractive indexes $n_1$ and $n_2$ with wavelengths?

Comment: @NominalAnimal it s from my university...

Comment: @fleablood tg = tangens, $\lambda =$ wavelength

Comment: @trilolil: Professors make as many mistakes as everybody else. Sure, I'm an ornery fellow, and I guess my professors groan every time they see me, because I don't trust any authority without question. That said, I now understand what is going on: Thin film interference and [Snell's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law) -- $\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}=\frac{n_2}{n_1}$ -- although I don't know which $\lambda$ corresponds to which $n$ yet. I'll outline the full explanation as an answer, and find out myself too.

Comment: @NominalAnimal OK thx waiting for your response!

Comment: Took a bit longer than I thought, and became a lot longer than you probably would prefer, but hopefully it will clear up the difficulties you (and others) might have in this particular regard. If I missed anything, or confused something, add a comment, and I'll try my best to clarify/fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at a larger image, from the Wikipedia article on [thin-film interference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin-film_interference):
[image: Thin-film interference]
*(Licensed under the [Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/deed.en) license by the author, [Nicoguaro](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Nicoguaro))*

First, [optical path length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_path_length) is the distance light travels in some medium (or vacuum), multiplied by the [refractive index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index) of that medium. Refractive index $n$ is the ratio of velocity of light in vacuum $c$ and the phase velocity of light $v$ in some medium, $n = c/v$. Essentially, optical path length tells us the "phase distance" the light travels; the number of wavelengths multiplied by wavelength.

[Snell's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law) describes the effects of refraction at the boundary between two media:
$$\frac{\sin\theta_1}{\sin\theta_2} = \frac{v_1}{v_2} = \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2} = \frac{n_2}{n_1}$$
where $\lambda_1$ is the wavelength in medium 1 (white), and $\lambda_2$ is the wavelength in medium 2 (light blue). Note the inverted order for refractive indexes.

Let $L$ be the difference in optical path lengths for the reflected light in the above diagram:
$$L = n_2\left(\overline{AB} + \overline{BC}\right) - n_1\overline{AD}$$
Using trigonometry, we can see that
$$\overline{AB} = \overline{BC} = \frac{d}{\cos \theta_2}$$
where $d$ is the thickness of the thin film ($a$ in OP's diagram, I assume; it seems to be cut off from the right side of the diagram, only the marker line is visible), and
$$\overline{AD} = \overline{AC} \sin\theta_1 = \left [ \left( \overline{AB} + \overline{BC} \right) \sin\theta_2 \right ] \sin\theta_1 = 2 d \tan\theta_2 \sin\theta_1$$
Therefore,
$$L = \frac{2 n_2 d}{\cos\theta_1} - 2 n_1 d \tan\theta_2 \sin\theta_1$$

For constructive interference, the difference in optical path lengths must be an integer multiple of wavelength (in medium 1), $\lambda_1$:
$$L = N\lambda_1, \; \; N \in \mathbb{N}$$

Now, in OP's derivation, we see

> $$\frac{\overline{AB} + \overline{BC}}{\lambda_n} - \frac{\overline{A'C}}{\lambda_0} = N$$

I do not know what the original author of that line was smoking, but there certainly is an error right there. The above is nonsense. First, the drawn location for $A'$ makes absolutely no sense; it is purely at the wrong location. The marked location has nothing to do with the optical paths, nor reflection, nor refraction, nor interference. Second, the two reflected light paths are parallel. The angle of the reflected light paths is $\theta_1$ from vertical, making angle $\angle ADC$ 90°. (Angle $\angle DAC = 90° - \theta_1$, and that's why angle $\angle ACD = \theta_1$.) The point $A'$ should be at $D$: along the upper reflected light path, perpendicular to the point where the second reflected light path, the refracted light path, emerges from the second medium. This is the point where phases should match for constructive interference between the two optical paths! Third, the subscripts $\lambda_n$ and $\lambda_0$ make no sense, since $1$ is used for incident light, and $2$ for reflected (and refracted) light.

This is a classic fudge: whoever wrote the formula, remembered the details wrong, and didn't bother to check, and instead wrote something that looks, and at a quick check computes correctly.

We can check what it should be, by dividing our $L = \lambda_1 N$ by $\lambda_1$:
$$\frac{L}{\lambda_1} = \frac{n_2}{\lambda_1} \left(\overline{AB} + \overline{BC}\right) - \frac{n_1}{\lambda_1} \overline{AD} = N$$
But that's about it. We could apply $n_2/\lambda_1 = n_1/\lambda_2$ from Snell's law, but I don't see how it would help; this line in the OP's expression is just nonsense.

Let's get back on track, and to the core of OP's actual question.

We have
$$L = \frac{2 n_2 d}{\cos\theta_1} - 2 n_1 d \tan\theta_2 \sin\theta_1 = N \lambda_1, \; N \in \mathbb{N}$$
Write the $\tan$ as $\sin/\cos$:
$$L = 2 d \frac{n_2}{\cos\theta_1} - 2 d \frac{n_1 \sin\theta_2 \sin\theta_1}{\cos\theta_2} = N \lambda_1$$
From Snell's law, we can apply $$n_1 \sin\theta_1 = n_2 \sin\theta_2$$
in the second term (the one with two $\sin$'s), so we get
$$L = 2 d \frac{n_2}{\cos\theta_1} - 2 d \frac{n_2 \sin\theta_2 \sin\theta_2}{\cos\theta_2} = N \lambda_1$$
Now we can combine terms, to get
$$L = 2 n_2 d \left ( \frac{1 - \sin^2\theta_2}{\cos\theta_2} \right ) = N \lambda_1$$
We know from trigonometry that $$\cos(x) = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2(x)}$$
Therefore, $$1-\sin^2(x) = \cos^2(x)$$and$$\frac{1 - \sin^2\theta_2}{\cos\theta_2} = \frac{\cos^2\theta_2}{\cos\theta_2} = \cos\theta_2$$
Note that if you have `gnuplot` installed, you can simply run `set xrange[0:2*pi]; plot (1-sin(x)**2)/cos(x), cos(x)` and see the two curves overlap. It is easier to find the answer when you know what to look for!

Applying the above to $L$ we get
$$L = 2 n_2 d \cos \theta_2 = N \lambda_1$$

---

Even in an University, one should not simply trust an authority, when they make a claim. Always be inquisitive first, respectful second. Examine the claims and statements, and try to "slot" them into the whole picture. If you perceive gaps or discontinuities, it is your duty to ask.

Professors and lecturers are only human, and make occasional typos, thinkos, or other errors, and occasionally even accidentally skip important stuff because they're so familiar with it. Asking questions pertinent to the matter at hand, explaining the perceived gap/discontinuity, **shows respect** in my opinion: it shows one is following the lecture content closely, and *trusts* the professor or lecturer to be critical, even of their own work.

Without asking questions, we never discover new. We just learn to parrot what others have discovered. That is not the purpose of a University. (If it is the purpose of *your* university, I'd wholeheartedly suggest switching to a proper one.)

I am not a professor, or have my PhD yet, but I have lectured, and I do eat my own dogfood (as described above). In fact, I love it. I am painfully aware of my own limitations, of how often I am wrong, and how limited my own viewpoint is without the observations of others. With good questions, I myself can learn also, which makes lecturing much more fun, in my opinion.